# Inserting a row in a Pandas dataframe converts NaN into NaT

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Let's start with a dataframe that looks like this:

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
from dateutil import tz
from pandas import DataFrame

date1 = datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 1, 9, 15, 0, 0, tzinfo=tz.tzoffset(None, -5 * 60 * 60))
df = DataFrame({"date": [date1], "a": [1.0], "b": [2.0]})
```

In this dataframe, `dtypes` are `TimeStamp`, `float64` and `float64`. Now I need to insert a row to another date with `NaN` values. I did something like this:

```
date2 = date1 + timedelta(seconds=300)
row = {"date": date2, "a": np.nan, "b": np.nan}
df = df.append(row, ignore_index=True)
```

My problem is that this new row was inserted with `NaT`s instead of `NaN`s. Dataframe `dtypes` become `TimeStamp`, `object` and `object`. `NaN`s have been converted as `TimeStamp`s, which is not what I expected.

Any ideas why this is happening and how to avoid it? I want `NaN`s to remain as `float` in my dataframe.

I also tried the following:

```
date2 = date1 + timedelta(seconds=300)
row = {"date": np.nan, "a": np.nan, "b": np.nan}
df = df.append(row, ignore_index=True)
df.iloc[0, 1] = date2
```

Doing that, my dataframe `dtypes` become `object`, `float64` and `float64`. `NaN`s remain numeric, but now dates are plain `object`s.

To give some context, this dataframe is built using another module that connects to a database to extract time series between two dates. Dates in these series have a 5-minute gap, but data may be missing at a given date. I have to insert rows of `NaN`s in this dataframe for missing dates.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually NaT also act as NaN but in terms of Date...you can also normally fill them or filter them as you usually do with NaN's.....but if you want to repace NaT to NaN then try `df=df.replace(pd.NaT,np.nan)`

Comment: @AnuragDabas Indeed, you are right, replacing `pd.NaT` with `np.nan` works. But this does not explain why `NaN`s are replaced by `NaT`s during insertion. If there is no other option, I'll stick to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to get around this issue would be to convert your row to a dataframe first:

```
date2 = date1 + timedelta(seconds=300)
row = {"date": date2, "a": np.nan, "b": np.nan}
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([row]), ignore_index=True)
```

I don't know why this issue occurs in the first place though

Comment: Thanks! It gives what I've been expecting. I don't understand why adding a row as dictionary works like that either, but your solution is clean enough for me.